# How can I append every filename as a List value in a variable?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to make a List variable that contains all the globbed files's filename as it's value.

so far, I'm able to get the file names but I can't seem to make a List out of it. here's my code:

```
let g:test = {}
let g:test+=glob("~/Projects/js/*")
```

What seems to be wrong?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [glob()](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#glob())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`:h glob()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#glob%28%29)

If you see a third optional parameter named `{list}`, then your version of Vim can directly return a List. If you pass 1 here, you'll have a list.

If not, you'll have to [`:split()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#split%28%29) `glob()` result.